# Mirror Bash history

Tags: bash, command-history

I teach in various CLI tools like git,docker etc.
I want to have two bash terminals: one for running commands, and get output, and one that at all time just mirroring what the command history would give me.

Is it possible to mirror realtime commands in bash like that?

Example:

T1: pwd

T1: /home/me

T1: ls

T1: Documents Desktop Downloads

T2:

```
pwd
ls
```

Answer (score 2):

So, lets split the problem into two parts:

First, you need to make sure, that bash history is being updated immediately. Everytime you type any input and hit enter, the command should be written to `.bash_history`.

This can be achieved by adding something like following into your `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -c; history -r'
```

Second, you want to read the `.bash_history` file constantly. For that you can use the `tail` command in your second terminal:

```
tail -f .bash_history
```

the `-f` parameter means, that tail keeps the file open and prints new line as they are being written.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the command printed *before* it is executed, it is fairly complicated using a bash DEBUG trap, but look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/175802/458747) and [the long version](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec). Here's a simple version. Create a file, say `~/traceme` with contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
# run preexec on each cmd before execute it
# see https://superuser.com/a/175802/458747
preexec(){ 
    echo "$1" >>~/myhistory
}
preexec_invoke_exec(){
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # do nothing if completing
    # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return 
    local this_command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | 
                                         sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//");
    preexec "$this_command"
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

and in your T1 terminal do `source ~/traceme`. Then in T2 do `tail -f ~/myhistory`.  Every command you enter in T1 will be written to the end of the file that is tailed in T2, before it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is a viable option for you as you asked about bash. But zsh writes history directly to `.zsh_history`. So you could have one terminal `tail -f .zsh_history`.  And use another zsh terminal for the actual commands.

But that is if you are willing to use zsh.